# Why is my toolbarItem label offset?

Tags: macos, toolbar, xcode8

Writing an app for macOS using Xcode 8.2. After adding a toolbar to my window and a NSSegmentedControl, the label `View` for the toolbar item is not centered. Both in the storyboard and as the app is running.

Why?

[image]

Comment: While your app is running, could you please go to **Debug** → **View Debugging** → **Show View Frames** in Xcode and post a screenshot of what your window looks like with that setting enabled?

Comment: @Bob Thanks for the hint. When I turned on Show Alignment Rectangles, I saw that that the view ToolbarItem was too wide. Apparently the maximum size width equals actual width for the frame. Give an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Cool.  Just next time you come back to this feature, keep in mind that *View Frames* and *Alignment Rectangles* do different things, so make sure you select the correct one to avoid getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the size of your toolbar item is mismatched to the size of the view.  If you change the maximum size of your toolbar item so that it can't expand beyond the size of the segmented control, you should be good to go.